# Selecting Soap XML node children in .net

Tags: c#, .net, xml, soap

I have the following SOAP response:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<env:Header/>
<env:Body>  
<GetSalesResponse xmlns="http://api.dgm-uk.com/Publisher/schemas">
<status>ok</status>
-<sales>
     -<sale>
      <saleid>***</saleid>
      <campaignname>***</campaignname>
      <campaignid>***</campaignid>
      <advertisername>***</advertisername>
      </sale>
      -<sale>
      <saleid>***</saleid>
      <campaignname>***</campaignname>
      <campaignid>***</campaignid>
      <advertisername>***</advertisername>
      </sale> 
      ..............etc
```

Now, I was able to get all the sale elements using this code:

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlFile.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("soapenv", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
nsmgr.AddNamespace("GSR", "http://api.dgm-uk.com/Publisher/schemas");
var items = xmlFile.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/GSR:GetSalesResponse/GSR:sales", nsmgr);
```

How can I then while iterating the sale elements, select their inner children like saleid and campaignid? I just can't select them

Comment: Are you able to use LINQ to XML instead of the XmlDocument API? It'd make it a lot simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works...

```
XElement doc = XElement.Load("c:\\dd.xml");
XNamespace ns1 = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
XNamespace ns2 = "http://api.dgm-uk.com/Publisher/schemas";

var items = doc.Descendants(ns1 + "Body").Descendants(ns2 + "GetSalesResponse").Descendants(ns2 + "sales").Descendants(ns2 + "sale")
.Select((x) => new
{
saleid = x.Element(ns2 + "saleid").Value,
campaignname = x.Element(ns2 + "campaignname").Value,
campaignid = x.Element(ns2 + "campaignid").Value,
advertisername = x.Element(ns2 + "advertisername").Value
});

foreach (var itm in items)
{
Console.WriteLine("saleid:" + itm.saleid);
Console.WriteLine("campaignid:" + itm.campaignid);
Console.WriteLine("campaignname:" + itm.campaignname);  
Console.WriteLine("advertisername:" + itm.advertisername);
}
```

Comment: but how do you iterate through the sale vars?